# Laravel Spark - Notifications stuck & Stripe nagging for publishing key that exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

Just curious if anyone else is facing this issue with Laravel Spark where the notifications are intermittently stuck in loading and if there's a simple fix for it?

Ie:
[image]

Also, I'm receiving this Stripe error in my error console whenever I attempt to subscribe on my production environment, I am using the correct test credentials in the environment file:

```
Uncaught Error: You did not set a valid publishable key. Call Stripe.setPublishableKey() with your publishable key. For more info, see https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js
    at Function.b.validateKey ((index):3)
    at Function.b.create ((index):2)
    at Function.c.createToken ((index):2)
    at o.subscribe (app.js:27)
    at click (eval at pa (app.js:67), <anonymous>:3:52019)
    at e (app.js:67)
    at HTMLButtonElement.t._withTask.t._withTask (app.js:67)
```

In my .env file I have (I have put x's in for the purpose of this question, the env file has the real keys):

```
STRIPE_MODEL=App\User
STRIPE_KEY=pk_test_Nq6IKWIFjSaBFngxxxxxxxxx
STRIPE_SECRET=sk_test_T9lwCHZACcty5JUxxxxxxxxx
```

*app/services.php* and *app/services-stripe.php* both have these settings:

```
'stripe' => [
    'model'  => App\User::class,
    'key'    => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
],
```

Any assistance is appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: FYI, I did `php artisan cache:clear` and also `composer dumpauto` with these things, I'm not new to the quirks - that's why I'm resorting to outside help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same situation with the notifications.  Apparently there's some kind of conflict with font awesome's spinner.  I removed the icon completely and it's working now.  Same with invitations, when I send an invitation, the text on the button changes but the spinner never hides.

Comment: I changed it to the new Font Awesome format of `<i class="fal fa-spinner-third"></i>` and that honestly seems to have fixed the notifications eternal load... weird?

Comment: Did you experience any issues with Stripe as well?

Comment: That's weird, some issues with fa 5 I guess.  No, I didn't have any issues with Stripe.